# Restore XAMPP database

Tags: mysql

I have a complete backup of my `XAMPP` installation.
Unfortunately I forgot to export my database to `.sql` files. But as mentioned i have all `.frm`, `.idb` and `ibdata1` `ib_logfile*` and so on.

However if I simply copy the backed up files into the `/opt/lampp/var/mysql` directory I get the following error:

(Switching back to the original directory created by the `XAMPP` installation is completely fine, though.)

> Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.

and

> phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server
>   rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and
>   password in your  configuration and make sure that they correspond to
>   the information given  by the administrator of the MySQL server.

For my `/opt/lampp/var/mysql` folder I did

```
sudo chown -R mysql mysql
sudo chgrp -R mysql mysql
```

What am I missing to restore the database from the `XAMPP` backup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why I didn't try this earlier, but a simple reboot resolved this issue. Note, that the simple restart of xampp and thus of mysql and apache did not work.

Answer (score 0):

(Not necessarily a total answer, but some clues of how to move forward.)

"Complete backup" -- Do you mean all the files?  If you have all the files in the mysql directory tree, then you have everything except for `my.cnf`, which is located elsewhere (and probably backed up?).

There are no `.sql` files in a normal installation, so I don't understand that issue.

The 'rejected connection' sounds like the reload mixed up the data files you dumped, some of which contain the user/pwd info with a fresh install of MySQL, which does not have such.

Can you get in with user=`root` and no password?  If so, one approach is to recreate the users and passwords.  (But first check that the rest of the data is intact.)